# Resizing logo in small screen sizes not working

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

[I have a website here](http://ambergoodwindraft.com/insideoutfitnessdraft/) for a friend and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get that logo resized to have a width of 300px. I can resize the .site-title a just fine but that doesn't resize the logo and I have no img tag to work as it's been set as a header image from wordpress.

I can't figure out the right css statement to get to that logo to resize it once the screen size hits 400px.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="title-area">
  <p itemprop="headline" class="site-title">
   <a title="Insideout Fitness" href="http://ambergoodwindraft.com/insideoutfitnessdraft/">Insideout Fitness</a>
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS -- It's hard to show the css as some of it's me and some of it's from the wordpress theme.

```
.header-image .site-title a {
    height: 130px;
    margin: 1em 0;
    max-width: 417px;
}
```

I thought with this method it would work but it didn't

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    .header-image .site-header .title-area .site-title a {
        background-size: contain !important;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .header-image .site-title a {
           background-size:contain!important;            
           height: auto !important;
           margin: 0;
          max-width: 417px;
          padding: 11% 0;
    }
}
```

In my part, I usually use img in logo when it comes to responsive because img display a smooth way. You background the image in anchor, in my experience it is very difficult to make your logo display in a smooth way, but just try my code.
Let me know the output.

Answer (score 0):

Take the style out of the `head` of your site; that's going to override anything you put in your stylesheet. In **style.css** you'll want something like:

```
.site-title a {
    background: url("http://ambergoodwindraft.com/insideoutfitnessdraft/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/insideout-fitness-logo.png") no-repeat 0 0 / 300px auto;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to put this in a media query, if you only want it to be 300px wide on mobile devices. Otherwise...why not just resize the image to the proper size, and re-upload it?